# Join arrays of evaluated values in Playwright/Node/JS

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, playwright

I am trying to scrape a page with multiple searchresults with Playwright in Node.
Scraping the different individual elements is easy. But how can I join them in an array so the individual elements are joined in one node?

This is what I have:

```
var myArray = [];
const titles = await page.$$eval('//h3', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim().split('\n')[0]))
const prices = await page.$$eval('.price', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim().split('\n')[0]))
myArray.push(String(titles) + String(prices));


console.log(titles); gets me this :    ['ProductTitleOne', 'ProductTitleTwo']   
console.log(prices); gets me this :    ['456','123']

console.log(myArray);  results in this ['ProductTitleOne', 'ProductTitleTwo','456','123']
```

I want something like: [{'ProductTitleOne','456'}, {'ProductTitleTwo','123'}]
(or this: {{'ProductTitleOne','456'}, {'ProductTitleTwo','123'}}   )

The following attempts have also failed :

```
const combined1 = [].concat(titles, prices);
let get_all = [...titles, ...prices];
```

Have investigated mapping, arrays, indexing, and have looked at many Stackoverflow questions, but still have no clue on how to solve this. If anyone has some pointers on how to solve this, much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
const result = titles.map((title, index)=> ({ title, price: prices[index]}));
```